# Use Mustache with PlayFramework

Tags: playframework, mustache, playframework-1.x

How can I use the play-mustache module (http://www.playframework.org/modules/mustache-head/home) as the default template rendering engine on the server side?

The way the documentation goes, it seems that I have to invoke mustache.print every time I need to render a template. This does not make much sense, because I do not want to wrap every mustache template in a groovy template, which will invoke and render it. I would like this to happen behind the scenes, i.e. when a controller action renders, the renderer should use Mustache instead of groovy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could just call

```
MustacheSession session = MustachePlugin.session();
String html = session.toHtml("yourTemplate.html",data);
renderHtml(html);
```

https://github.com/murz/play-mustache/blob/master/app/play/modules/mustache/MustacheTags.java#L35

I can't say I understand how the Scope class in Mustache works, but here is a link: where data is Map used by the mustache Scope class
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.github.spullara.mustache.java/core/0.6/com/sampullara/mustache/Scope.java